# Counting a particular word in a string using Zapier code

Tags: javascript, python, zapier

I use Zapier to automate many of our business functions, which is great, but I got stuck trying to count the number of arrays or, if you like, a particular word pattern that comes from a string. I can tidy up the string with Zapier formatter, but cannot figure out how to carry out a count.

Here is an example of a tidied string where " have been removed:

```
[{Name:Jon,Surname:Smith},{Name:David,Surname:Michael},{Name:Sam,Surname:Fields},{Name:Katy,Surname:Milnes}]
```

In this instance I would want the count on say "Name" to return 4.

I have looked at different code examples for counting words but cannot execute them correctly in the code action of Zapier. This is probably really straight forward but I do not come from a coding background so a simple Java (or Python) script to drop into the Zapier code action or some pointers on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide code examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Tried using variants around:

function myFunction() {
    var str = "name, name, name"; 
    var res = str.match(/name/g).length;
}
output = {id: 1234, name: res};

Comment: are you getting the json string object as an input?

Answer (score 0):

What are you really trying to achieve by trying to count the word?

Do you just want to know the number of objects the array contains? If that is the case something like this would work. Assuming that the array is in your `inputData` for the code step.

```js
var data = JSON.stringify([{'Name':'Jon', 'Surname':'Smith'},{'Name':'David','Surname':'Michael'},{'Name':'Sam','Surname':'Fields'},{'Name':'Katy','Surname':'Milnes'}]);
var inputData = {objArr: data};

// Do not insert the above lines in your code step. 
// Set the objArr to your array in the inputData step.

var parsedObjArr = JSON.parse(inputData.objArr);
// Skip the above step if the array is not in the inputData object.

var arrLen = parsedObjArr.length
console.log('Array Length: ', arrLen);

// The line below outputs data from the code step.  
output = {arrLen}
```

Also **note**, you do not need to remove the quotes from the JSON string.

If the array is not in the `inputData` of the code step, you can just directly use the `length` method on the array.

Comment: Thank you. Yes just trying to count the number of objects in the array. I will give this a go and report back!

Answer (score 0):

Well in Python you can convert the json string into dictionary with key as the name. Length of dictionary is what you are looking for. Here is the example:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
x=json.dumps([{'Name':'Jon', 'Surname':'Smith'},{'Name':'David','Surname':'Michael'},{'Name':'Sam','Surname':'Fields'},{'Name':'Katy','Surname':'Milnes'}])
json_string=json.loads(x)
for obj in json_string:
    if(obj['Name'] in d):
        d[obj['Name']].append([obj['Name']+' '+obj['Surname']])
    else:
        d[obj['Name']]=[obj['Name']+' '+obj['Surname']]
print(len(d))
```

Comment: Thank you also. I will try both solutions later his week. I really appreciate the help.